# how to clear error while starting app with pm2?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, backend, pm2

Im working with a vue-cli project and when i run pm2 start server.js im getting error in npm.
its working properly when npm run start is used

```
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [server](ids: [ 1 ])
[PM2] [server](1) ✓
[PM2] Process successfully started
┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ app       │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 12560    │ 2m     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 42.7mb   │ jayas    │ disabled │
│ 2   │ npm       │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 60   │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ jayas    │ disabled │
│ 1   │ server    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 6020     │ 0s     │ 45   │ online    │ 0%       │ 29.9mb   │ jayas    │ disabled │
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm run serve --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "brcypt": "^1.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^4.2.0",
    "node-cmd": "^3.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "pm2": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

the versions are

windows 10
node version 12.18.3
npm version 6.14.6
PM2 version 4.4.1

Comment: Care to elaborate what the error actually is?

Comment: the app and server status is online but npm shows errored. Im not sure how to clear it @mahatmanich

Comment: @JayashreeK check with pm2 log ID, it show the log of your process

Comment: 2|npm      | C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1
2|npm      | :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
2|npm      | ^
2|npm      | 
2|npm      | SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
2|npm      |     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
2|npm      |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
2|npm      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)

Comment: im getting this error @mahatmanich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run:

```
pm2 reset <appName>
```

will reset the counters and you will be able to restart the errored app